# How to get number of login and logout done by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Can anyone suggest an approach I should follow to get a number of logins and logout done by a user in the report. 
I need to implement an API in .net core which provides such a report.

Comment: This is greatly dependent on the way in which you handle the membership. Are you using ASP.NET Identity or your bespoke implementation?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I can say that for  Bespoke development, as tracking of number of user log in and log out give us number that how frequently application used by user. I am using ASP.NET CORE.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this mechanism in the Beckend code.
Create a new table in the DB for log in users and count each entrance.
Create a new API point for this demand (update this table) and called this API point from the Frontend after the logged in success.